# Photoshop ScriptUI Slider Indicator

Tags: javascript, xml, javascript-objects, extendscript, photoshop-script

The script writes the slider indicator position value to the xml file. But it fails to read and set the xml value.

The alert box in the save/read xml functions lists the xml variables. I am expecting the slider indicator to match the numerical vlaue in the xml variable.

I have a feeling the issue is with the switch statements in the read/write xml functions. Are these lines correct?

Read function:
case 'slider': myXML[a] = o[a].value; break;

Write function:
case 'slider': o[a].value = myXML[a] != '' ? (myXML[a] == 'true' ? 1 : 0) : o[a].value; break;

Reference screenshots. The slider indicator is at 0 instead of 63.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
var w = new Window("dialog","test",undefined,{closeButton: true});  
var group1 = w.add("group");

mySlider = group1.add("slider");
    mySlider.minvalue = 0;
    mySlider.maxvalue = 100;
    //mySlider.value = 0;
    mySlider.preferredSize.length = 195;
    mySlider.preferredSize.height = 15;


mySliderEtxt = group1.add("edittext",undefined,"0");
    mySliderEtxt.preferredSize=[50,20];


mySlider.onChanging = function(){          
  mySliderEtxt.text = mySlider.value;
  }
mySliderEtxt.onChanging = function(){
  mySlider.value = mySliderEtxt.text;
  }
    

ok = group1.add("button", undefined, "Set", { name: "set" })
cancel = group1.add("button", undefined, "Close", { name: "close" })


settingsSlider1 = { sliderOne: mySlider, textItemOne: mySliderEtxt}


ok.onClick = function () {
  w.close()
  saveToXML(settingsSlider1, 'Simple Sider')
}

cancel.onClick = function () {
  w.close()
}


w.onShow = function () {
  readFromXML(settingsSlider1, 'Simple Sider')
}
w.show();



function saveToXML(o, xmlName) {
  var f = new File(Folder.desktop + '/' + xmlName + '.xml'),
      myXML = new XML('<variables></variables>');
  for (var a in o) {
      switch (o[a].type) {
          case 'edittext': myXML[a] = o[a].text; break;
          case 'checkbox': myXML[a] = o[a].value; break;
          case 'radiobutton': myXML[a] = o[a].value; break;
          case 'dropdownlist': myXML[a] = o[a].selection ? o[a].selection.text : ''; break;
          case 'slider': myXML[a] = o[a].value; break;
          
      }
  }
  alert('Save XML \n'+myXML);
  f.encoding = "UTF8"
  f.open('w');
  f.write(myXML.toXMLString())
  f.close();
}

function readFromXML(o, xmlName) {
  var f = new File(Folder.desktop + '/' + xmlName + '.xml');
  f.encoding = "UTF8";
  f.open('r');
  var myXML = new XML(f.read());
  f.close();

  for (var a in o) {
      switch (o[a].type) {
          case 'edittext': o[a].text = myXML[a] != '' ? myXML[a] : o[a].text; break;
          case 'checkbox': o[a].value = myXML[a] != '' ? (myXML[a] == 'true' ? 1 : 0) : o[a].value; break;
          case 'radiobutton': o[a].value = myXML[a] != '' ? (myXML[a] == 'true' ? 1 : 0) : o[a].value; break;
          case 'dropdownlist': o[a].selection = myXML[a] != '' ? o[a].find(myXML[a]) : 0; break;
          case 'slider': o[a].value = myXML[a] != '' ? (myXML[a] == 'true' ? 1 : 0) : o[a].value; break;
      }
  }
  alert('Read XML \n'+myXML);
  f.encoding = "UTF8"
  f.open('w');
  f.write(myXML.toXMLString())
  f.close();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set the `mySlider.value` after you load in the XML. You also have a typo in `Simple Sider`

Comment: Thank you for noticing the typo. Your observation is correct. I was able to update the slider indicator by adding the mySlider.value  after loading XML

Comment: This following change updates the indicator position:   w.onShow = function () {
  readFromXML(settingsSlider1, 'Simple Slider');
  mySlider.value = mySliderEtxt.text;
}

Comment: I also discovered that commenting out the switch statement case 'slider' in the readFromXML and saveToXML functions has no effect. When attempting to save slider values to XML, I'd like to know if there should be a switch statement case for the slider.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one line:

```
w.onShow = function () {
  readFromXML(settingsSlider1, 'Simple Sider');
  mySlider.value = mySliderEtxt.text; // <-------------- HERE
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what to add. I tried adding return. It did not make a difference

Comment: A took your code (as it is in your question), added the one line `mySlider.value = mySliderEtxt.text;` after the line `readFromXML(settingsSlider1, 'Simple Sider');` and it works just fine. Try it.

Comment: OK that is what I did too after your initial comment. My follow-up question was about the switch statement case 'slider' in the save toXMl and reafDromXML functions. The 'slider' case code lines appear to be unnecessary. The code works fine when the lines are commented out which is puzzling.